# Spawn perl script in colored console

Tags: windows, perl

In windows, I was thinking

```
system "start", "cmd.exe", "color" "25" "/k", "script.pl"
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: For one thing, it is standard to include commas between all the elements of a list.

Comment: And at SO, it is standard to include more information than "it doesn't work", like the actual error message you get, or a description of what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be able to to execute `start` at all with the multiple-argument form for `system` since `start` is a shell built-in. But a Perl <s>bug</s> feature on Windows pretends you said

```
system 'start "cmd.exe" "color" "25" "/k" "script.pl"'
```

Which brings us to `start`'s awful syntax. If the first argument is quoted, it's taken to be the window title. You want

```
system 'start "" "cmd.exe" "color" "25" "/k" "script.pl"'
```

or just

```
system 'start cmd color 25 /k script.pl'
```

Comment: I am following O'Reilly's _Learning Perl on Win32_: " Giving system a list rather than giving it a simple string saves one command shell process as well, so do this when you can." --Schwartz, Olson, and Christiansen

Comment: @user2795733, Like I said, if that was actually happening, you wouldn't be able to execute `start` as `start` is a shell builtin.

Comment: @user2795733, The only way to be sure to avoid the shell is to use `system({ $prog } $prog, @args)` instead of `system($prog, @args)`